# How can I convert this promise back into JSON array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

> I code this to get a JSON array from my sever

```
var students_list;
const library_address = 'http://localhost:17330'
async function data(a,b) {
    if(a == 'getdata')
    {
        const respone = await fetch(library_address + `/${a}/${b}`);
        const output = await respone.json();
        console.log(output);
        return output;
    }
}
```

> But the problem is I can't get the array outside of that function, the result give me a promise object instead

```
students_list = data('getdata','student') //promise
```

Comment: just use await .... students_list = await data('getdata','student');

Comment: The `data` function is `async`, so it needs to be awaited as well

Comment: `students_list = await data()`

Comment: No I can't, it created an error:

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Okay thank y'all. I'll using it by create another async function

Comment: Yes async function only return to a promise. so you are use then() or use await key word on  call data() function a another async function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var students_list;
const library_address = 'http://localhost:17330'
async function data(a,b) {
    if(a == 'getdata')
    {
        const respone = await fetch(library_address + `/${a}/${b}`);
        const output = respone.json(); // just  delete await
        console.log(output);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Once you use `async`, response will be a Promise object. You need use `await` to get what you want.